# How to fix XML validation error non-whitespace character are not allowed?

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, schema, whitespace

Eclipse throws validation error on this

> s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema
>   elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'

for the below XML file. Please help me find out the issue. There appears to be none.

```
<databaseChangeLog 
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">  
    ... 
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found :)

Eclipse > Preferences > Network Connections > Cache > Remove All
and 
Clean Build.

Reference : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=152355